# Serialize and Deserialize arbitrary value using Jackson

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have a request json in the format:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    .
    ..
    ...
    "keyn": "valuen",
    "generic": {
        "key1":"string-type-value1"
        "key2":"string-type-value2"
        "key3":"complex-type-value3"
        .
        ..
        ...
        "keyn": "simple/complex-valuen"
    }
}
```

As we can see, there is a property called **generic** .This property was initially made to accept arbitrary key-value pairs in String format only. Hence,we created a property `Map<String,String>`

The future requirement is such that we should also be able to accept arbitrary complex type value(such as list,array,etc) and not only String.

Is there a less-complex way to serialize/deserialize for this use-case using Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This property was initially made to accept arbitrary key-value pairs in String format only. Hence, we created a property `Map<String, String>`. [...] we should also be able to accept arbitrary complex type value(such as list,array,etc) and not only String.

Use a `Map<String, Object>` instead.